# Move one more vector to the vector of vectors?

Tags: c++, vector, stl, c++17

I have the structure `vector<vector<x>> a` and one more `vector<x> v`. I need to append this new vector to the existing vector of vectors (as new a item, not to concatenate), but it is long and I do not need it afterwards, so I would like to move the contents instead:

As of the time of writing, the code is trivial:

```
 a.push_back(v);
```

that obviously works. Can this be optimized like

```
 a.push_back(std::move(v));
```

or somehow else?

Comment: Yes. Why not just try it?

Comment: Because I have some fears it may work just by chance and not always. Due that I wanted somebody more experienced in advanced C++ to look at this but should not be unusual need to do so I think may make into question

Comment: It will use [std::vector::push_back (2)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back)  _"...value is moved into the new element...."_

Comment: This is exactly the circumstance that move semantics were created for.

Comment: From the comments it looks this may work. I would accept the answer if posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this will definitely work. As you can read in the definition of `std::move` [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move),

> std::move is used to indicate that an object t may be "moved from", i.e. allowing the efficient transfer of resources from t to another object. In particular, std::move produces an xvalue expression that identifies its argument t. It is exactly equivalent to a static_cast to an rvalue reference type.

So the result can be interpreted as *rvalue reference*.

And if we then look at the description of the `std::vector`s `push_back` function [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back), then we will find

> void push_back( T&& value )

which will "move the value into the new element"

So, your approach will work.